# Error: save() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I'm trying to add a date to the slug on save after I click Publish in the Wagtail admin panel i get en error `save() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

I'm quite new to python and Django/Wagtail so any help at this point would be grate.

```
def save(self, **kwargs):
    now = dt.datetime.now()
    if self.slug:
        self.slug = f"{self.slug}-{now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H-%I-%S')}"
    super().save(self, **kwargs)
```

Thank you

Comment: Don't pass self when calling save.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of

```
super().save(self, **kwargs)
```

call

```
super().save(**kwargs)
```

No need to pass self when you are calling save function in super class.